# How to get notified when user clicked anywhere in a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a extension similar to [Chrome dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) . For building that i my extension should be notified when user left clicked on a webpage on any tab.

I searched all over the chrome.* APIs but failed to find that kind of event. Also tried googling with this query : "*how to get notified when user clicks on a webpage in chrome api*". Failed to get any result.

Is this prohibited in chrome api ? I found that  [Extensions can't listen to tabs and navigation buttons](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-interact-chrome) but as far as i understand that is not relevant with my issue.

Any suggestion in how to get this done is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about chrome api, but is this `$(document).click(function(){console.log('clicked in doc');})` work ?

Comment: @Jashwant thanks for the info . I will try it but probably it will not work in a google chrome extension .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to attach a content script to all pages

[Google Chrome Extensions: Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

In that script attach a listener to the document to catch all clicks (like @Jashwant said) then pass a message back to your extension to perform some behaviour:

[Google Chrome Extensions: Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: Thanks @Bob . It sounds like that it will work . I will give it a try and confirm that it works or not